# cookies array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

i have this code in controller

```php
$cookie = json_decode(Cookie::get('newUser'));

$newUserArray = array(
    'name' => $request->input('name'),
    'email' => $request->input('email'),
    'phone' => $request->input('phone')
);
$newcookie = json_encode(array($addressCookieArray));
```

then i return it to view

```
return redirect()->back()->withCookie(Cookie::make('newUser', $newcookie, $time));
```

any idea how if i just want to view only a phone cookie data. this is what i have try

```
{{ Request::hasCookie('newUser') ?  Cookie::get('phone') : $UserInfo->phoneNum }}
```

Comment: what error you found

Answer (score 0):

To view only the phone number you would need to convert the json string back to an array and get the phone number:

```php
json_decode(Cookie::get('newUser'))->phone
```